# String.equals() always return true

Tags: java, android, string

K want to compare two strings but the `equals()` method always return true , so the if statement always runs. why this happens?

```
resultString = "Test1";
String CompleteString = "Test";
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString));
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`if(CompleteString.equals(resultString));` <-- remove the `;`

Your code is the equivalent to :

```
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString))
{
  //empty block
}
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);
}
```

So if equals returns true, the empty block will be executed, and after the second block will be **always** executed whatever the if was `false` or `true`.

Comment: Thanks , i didn't see that! sometimes making such a stupid mistake make me mad

Comment: i made mistake because i didn't see that semicolon,sometimes happens but i don't understand the downvote? this sites made for such questions , some of them difficult to solve and some of them is easy!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `;` after the if statement.

```
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString))
{
  rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `;` from `if(CompleteString.equals(resultString));`

`;` means end of statement so even the `if()` loop `returns` `false` or `true` all the statements present after `if()` will be executed.So `rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);` will be executed all the time.

**try this way**

```
resultString = "Test1";
String CompleteString = "Test";
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString))// removed `;`
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is because of the ';' at the end of if . Just remove and it will work !

Answer (score 2):

```
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString));
```

It won't enter in if block it looks like a empty condition :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of semicolon in if condition..

Correct code

```
resultString = "Test1";
String CompleteString = "Test";
if(CompleteString.equals(resultString))
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);
}
```